# Android UI not updating in onLoadFinished

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

In my application I get results from LoaderManager..

After onLoadFinished() method call,

In my listview update the data`s - it works correctly.

*My Problem:*

But **if(data.getCount>0)**
I want to hide my progress bar & empty list message layout.
My log message print correctly data count > 0.

But my view hiding code only not working..

Note:I test the outside of onLoadFinshed method my view hiding code works..

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    listAdapter.changeCursor(data); //works
    try {
        if (data.getCount() > 0) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("onLoadFinished()count>0", TAG);//works
                    mView.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress).setVisibility(View.GONE);//not working
                    Log.d("onLoadFinished2 count>0", TAG);//works
                    mView.findViewById(R.id.customer_no_items).setVisibility(View.GONE);//not working
            }
            }, 500);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to ASyncTask and use it's methods like onPostExecute() for updating the UI.

Comment: Try losing the Handler. Since, there is no need for it as the function onLoadFinished() is running on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you works with your views on UI thread. You can try to use this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        Log.d("onLoadFinished()count>0", TAG);//works
                mView.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress).
                setVisibility(View.GONE);//not working
                Log.d("onLoadFinished2 count>0", TAG);//works
                mView.findViewById(R.id.customer_no_items).
                 setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Or better way to be delete your thread fron method

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
listAdapter.changeCursor(data); //works
Log.d("onLoadFinished()count>0", TAG);//works
                mView.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress).setVisibility(View.GONE);//not working
                Log.d("onLoadFinished2 count>0", TAG);//works
                mView.findViewById(R.id.customer_no_items).setVisibility(View.GONE);//not working

    }
```